# how to change image after clicking submit button?

Tags: javascript

I want a code for questionnaire. with each question answered (text format) image change with the click of submit and progress bar increase.

I have to change 3 things with one click.

1. question
2. image
3. progress bar

```
<script>
    var img_array = ['placehold.it/100x100/green';, 'placehold.it/100x100/blue';, 'placehold.it/100x100/red']; 
    i = 0; 
    function myFunction() { 
        i++; 
        document.getElementById("myImg").src = img_array[i]; if (i == img_array.length - 1) { i = -1; } 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: We don't provide code. We provide assistance with coding issues.

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: var img_array = ['http://placehold.it/100x100/green', 'http://placehold.it/100x100/blue', 'http://placehold.it/100x100/red'];
i = 0;

function myFunction() {
    i++;
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = img_array[i];
    if (i == img_array.length - 1) {
        i = -1;

    }

}

Comment: @Adil please format the code in your post.

Comment: @Adil why would you reject my edit? I was cleaning up your post.

Comment: Surely your JavaScript console is telling you about the syntax errors in your code.  Try looking at the error messages.

Comment: @script47 .. i haven't rejected your post...if it happen may be mistakenly..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the image for image then this is the sample

```
document.getElementById('theImage').src="image.png";
```

If you want to change the background image of a button then this is the sample

```
document.getElementById("button").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://image/1917/crossn.png')";
button.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
```

Comment: no its not a background image..its a separate image and progress bar

Comment: then you can use this syntax document.getElementById('theImage').src="image.png";

Comment: and what for the progress bar..?

Comment: Put a div and give background color like red.. when one thing is passed increase the width like this increase the width slowly ...so it will look like progressing

Comment: but how to link with image and question.its already in different div.

Comment: Keep the image at the end of the different question so when something is done you can change the image and it would be approriate and show the div for progress bar above the question so progress it clearly shown..

Comment: can you explain me which part

Answer (score 0):

I have to change 3 things with one click.
    question
    image
    progress bar

Sample html code:

```
<div id="myQuestion">Qeuestion1</div>
<img src="test" id="myImg" /><br/>
<progress id="progressId" value="0" max="100"></progress><br/>
<button id="buttonId" onClick="myFunction()">submit</button>
```

Sample javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var qus_array = ['Question1','Question2','Question3']
var img_array = ['placehold.it/100x100/green', 'placehold.it/100x100/blue', 'placehold.it/100x100/red']; 
var i = 0; 
     $('button').click(function(){
         i++; 
         document.getElementById("myQuestion").innerHTML = qus_array[i];
        document.getElementById("myImg").src = img_array[i]; 
         document.getElementById("progressId").value = 33*i; 
         if (i == img_array.length - 1) { i = -1; } 
     })
 });
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/2724/)